# texture corruption on Galaxy Note3 updated with KitKat 4.4.2 when back button pressed

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, galaxy

I add some textures to GL Surface, GL displays it, and I press back button, 
which means the GL thread stops, the activity destroys, and my application goes onto background. After that, somehow all the texts on the menus that the next activity displays goes corrupted looking images like rectangle and never recovered.

I have searched to solve this problem in stackoverflow and found this might be related with h/w acceleration. But, it doesn't seem to work on my circumstances and I really need a essential solution to this.

Are there anyone that can help me, or experience the same problem with mine?
The release date of my app is upcoming, and any information that you have would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call GLSurface.onPause () at the appropriate time? Among other things, this will release the OGL Display appropriately (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html look at the Activity Life-cycle section).

If this doesn't fix your problem then please provide code snippets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Turns out 'Force GPU Renering' menu of 'Developer options' causes this. The devices that are reproduced this error have been enabled for that option, and when I turned it off the corruption disappeared. I am really wondering the reasons. the reasons for differentiation between this options turned on versus off. I mean, before entering the functions that use GL, all is good, but once use the functions that use GL and then back to the previous screen, then corrupted. Could I get any information on this please?